# Looking for free and simple OS virtualisation software

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, operating-system

I've recently trie to re-use Virtual Box (6.0) with which I have had good experiences in the past, but recently it was much dissatisfying. My main OS is Windows 10 and I tried installing various Linux distributions, all of them got things like black screens (after installing VB's Guest Additions) or not being able to install Guest Additions or getting slow as if the OS was suffocating (even giving them more RAM didn't help) ...

I've read that VMware has a free software for OS virtualisation for personnal use but I'm very confused trying to find where to download it. First I'm not 100% sure which WMware software I should look for. It doesn't seem to be vSphere, I think it's WMware Workstation. So I downloaded WMware Workstation from the only page where I found it, but it only gives me the choice between entering a licence key or trying for 30 days. So, maybe was I read about a free option is deprecated or I'm still on a wrong path.

I'm looking for something as simple to use as possible and free for local personnal use.

Comment: have you installed the *VirtualBox Extension Pack* on your host (just to play it safe)? - this sounds at least partly like graphic issue: have you installed and updated the graphic driver of your host? **--** if the issue still exists you may try the still supported *VirtualBox 5.2*; if this works, you "found" a software bug of *VirtualBox 6.0* and should fill a bugreport: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Bugtracker

Comment: Thank you. I haven't installed the Extension Pack ... most likely something I missed. I will try that (and/or version 5.2) later tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I think "VMware Player" is the free version you are looking for. You should find it at several download portals.

But you cannot create your own VMs with it, you will only be able to "play" already prepared machines.

I personally did not experience exceptionally bigger problems with VirtualBox during the last time, but I am also not using Windows 10. Still, I set up an installation for someone. There were no problems with it (but it is only running Windows XP to be able to use older applications).

Comment: Well I need something where I can create VMs, unless pre-made Linux machine are available from reliable sources (I will only take official sites as reliable sources).
I will still try to solve VirtualBox problem (somebody suggested some things as comment to the question) or I'm still open to other software suggestions.

Comment: According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation_Player#Resources) "Many ready-made virtual machines [...] are available [...]". There are some sources given. But I cannot test something myself since I have no running VMware at hand.